# Cubic equation in pocket calculator

Tags: polynomials

Is it possible to input and automaticly get solutions for the cubic equation using Texas Instruments TI-30X IIS calculator?

Answer (score 1):

The TI-30X IIS does not have an equation solver or any built-in functionality that will allow solving cubics.

However, you can find the roots using [the cubic formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html) [see lines 54-56 "Cardano's formula"].

[This reference](https://epsstore.ti.com/OA_HTML/csksxvm.jsp?nSetId=81534) giving step-by-step instructions for using the quadratic formula on the TI-30X may also be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that, but I thought there is a workaround, just like for solving quadratic equation by using the formula.